# ReGex, How to find second instance of string

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

If I want to get the Name between “for” and “;” which is NISHER HOSE, can you help me find the correct regex expression as there is more than one "for’ and “;” in the string

Data Owner Approval Needed for Access Request #: 2137352 for NISHER HOSE; CONTRACTOR; Manager: MUILLER, TIM (TWM0069)

Using the regular expression `(?<=for).*(?=;)` I get the wrong match  `Access Request #: 2137352 for NISHER HOSE; CONTRACTOR` - see [screenshot on https://www.regextester.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwePj.png)

Thanks

Comment: Try   (?<=.*for)(\w|\s)*(?=;)  Provided the name is only alphanumeric with spaces it should work... your * was picking up everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to assert `for`  on the left, you should and make sure to not match `for` again **and** you should exclude matching a `;` while asserting there is one at the right.

```
(?<=\bfor )(?:(?!\bfor\b)[^;])+(?=;)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\bfor )` Assert `for`  at the left
- `(?:(?!\bfor\b)[^;])!` Match 1+ times any char except `;` if from the current position not directly followed by `for` surrounded by word boundaries
- `(?=;)` Assert `;` directly at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gLul2g/1)

Comment: Solved my issue perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
(?<=\bfor )(?![^;]*\bfor\b)[^;]+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/gjpa1p/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for                      'for '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^;]*                    any character except: ';' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for                      'for'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^;]+                    any character except: ';' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that there are two "for". If you want to catch the name then use the ":" as a delimiter to catch the second "for":

- Regex: `/:.*for(.+?);/gm`
- Demo: https://regex101.com/r/p3QY0o/1

[image]

The name will be captured in group 1. If you decide to use a lookahead/lookbehind just bear in mind that these may or may not be supported depending on the regex engine.

Comment: Thank you. From here would I have to use string manipulation to get just the name? Otherwise, how would I be able to just get the name from here.

Comment: A regex match returns the match and any captured groups. In this case you could find the name inside the group 1. Accessing it depends on the language but in general is just matter of doing `match[1]`.